# Animator get number of animations (Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, animation, controllers, mecanim

In C#, how would I get the number of animations in an Animator Controller?

So I want to find out how many animations there are in an Animator Controller, and have this number in script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`[SerializeField] Animator animator;
int NumberOfNonEmptyStates = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips.Length;`

This returns the number of non-empty states in the specified animator.
(I'm using Unity version 2018.3.4)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Version 5 and up, you can get all states in the Animation Controller. You will need to drill down to layer, state-machine and then finally state.

Follow these to get started:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController-layers.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorControllerLayer-stateMachine.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorStateMachine.html

Comment: Could you provide an example of code of how I would get the number of animations from an Animator controller?

Comment: Follow the links, they'll tell you how. The docs list all the members you need to access and they explain each one and what it gives you back

Comment: -1 Link only answers are quite worthless. Links rot. Additionally, the answer doesn't seem to answer the question.